# Can we say "I am friends"? If not, why can we say "I’ve been friends with..."?

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

> **I’ve been friends** with the Murkets for twenty years.

This is a sentence from [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-friends-with-somebody).

How can we explain this?
I thought when the pronoun was "I" we must say ***a friend*** not ***friends***. I understand the meaning, but what about structure?

I think there should be subject and complement agreement.
Sorry I cannot say what I mean in a better way!
I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: "I am a friend of Stephen" = "I am friends with Stephen" = "Stephen and I are friends" = Stephen is my friend" =  "I am Stephen's friend".  Isn't English wonderful :)